# tikz matrix with font size relative to another font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I'm trying to make a table (matrix in tikz) in which some rows must have a slightly reduced or increased font size. In my mwe i used `relsize` but it is not suitable here as it adjusts relatively to the document's current font size, not the font size set in the node options. Therefore since i used `\Large` i should get `\large` with `\smaller`, but i get `\small`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,resize}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  texttable/.style 2 args={column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={anchor=center, text width=#1, outer sep=0pt},
        every odd row/.style={font=#2}},
        every even row/.style={font=\smaller,},}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix at (0,0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    texttable={60mm}{\Large}, align=right] (tb1)
    {
    abc\\
    def\\
    ghi\\
    jkl\\};
\end{document}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State `#2\smaller`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  texttable/.style 2 args={
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={anchor=center, text width=#1, outer sep=0pt},
    every odd row/.style={font=#2},
    every even row/.style={font=#2\smaller},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix at (0,0) [
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  texttable={60mm}{\Large},
  align=right
] (tb1)
{
  abc\\
  def\\
  ghi\\
  jkl\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]